# MS Project : How to set Task Summary Name when importing from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-project

I'm using TargetProcess (scrum) to manage our projects and encode timesheets.
So I made a tool to extract all needed data from targetprocess to an excel file, then import this excel file to our MSProject file to update all data.
Everything works perfectly except one thing :

In the Import Wizard, as I want to update my MsProject file and not create a new one, I select the "Merge the data into the active project" option. I've an ID as "Merge Key".
The structure is :

1. Project
2. Epic
3. Feature

So I've 3 Levels.

When I do my import, if I've no new epic or feature, everything works correctly, all my data (time, complete, date, etc) are well updated.

But if there is a new Feature (for example), this new feature is append to the end of my MSProject file and it not placed in the correct project.

So for example, if I had :

- Project_A

  - Epic_A1

    - Feature_A1a
- Project_B

  - Epic_B1

    - Feature_B1a

and if I add a new feature "Feature_A1b" in the epic "Epic_A1" of project "Project_A" in TargetProcess (or the excel file used for import), the result after the new import (merge) will be :

- Project_A

  - Epic_A1

    - Feature_A1a
- Project_B

  - Epic_B1

    - Feature_B1a
    - Feature_A1b

instead of :

- Project_A

  - Epic_A1

    - Feature_A1a
    - Feature_A1b
- Project_B

  - Epic_B1

    - Feature_B1a

I tried to define the "Task Summary Name" in my excel file, and bind it to the "Task Summary Name" field in MsProject during the import, but MsProject don't care about it.

Is there any way to tell MsProject to append the new feature to the correct project and not at the end of the file ?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct--when the Import Wizard is used to merge data, new tasks are added at the end of the schedule.

The way around this is to avoid having the Import Wizard add the new tasks. Instead, before running the wizard, add placeholder tasks where you want the new tasks to go and update your merge source file with the Unique IDs of these placeholder tasks (presuming that's what is used as the primary key).